# Is it possible to serialize different property sets using DataContractJsonSerializer?

Tags: json, wcf, rest

I'm building a (hopefully) RESTful service using WCF and JSON.

For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    // This member is serialized.
    [DataMember]
    internal string FullName;

    // This is serialized even though it is private.
    [DataMember]
    private int Age;

    // This is not serialized because the DataMemberAttribute 
    // has not been applied.
    private string MailingAddress;

    // This is not serialized, but the property is.
    private string telephoneNumberValue;

    [DataMember]
    public string TelephoneNumber
    {
        get { return telephoneNumberValue; }
        set { telephoneNumberValue = value; }
    }
}
```

I need to return a Person object without telephone number (i.e. w/ FullName and Age only) from a WCF method, so I was wondering if it's somehow possible to do it using only attribute properties of Person class and WFC method?

Thanks

v.

Comment: I did not get the full context - if you remove `DataMember` attribute from `TelephoneNumer` property, wouldn't it answer your question (_return a Person object with FullName and Age only_)?

Comment: Well, you are absolutely right - I wasn't clear. I need the existing setup as well, and ability to decide which way the thing is going to be serialized - on per service method basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't do that, but here is an example of a way you can accomplish the same goal without a lot of work.

You will need to have two `Person` classes, one that has `PhoneNumber` with the `DataMember` attribute and one that doesn't.  The best way to do this would probably be to create two sub classes from the main `Person` class

```
[DataContract]
public class PersonWithoutPhone
{
    private Person _p;

    public PersonWithoutPhone(Person p)
    {
        _p = p;
    }

    [DataMember]
    internal string FullName
    {
        get { return _p.FullName; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    private int Age
    {
        get { return _p.Age; }
    }

    public string TelephoneNumber
    {
        get { return _p.TelephonNumber; }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class PersonWithPhone
{
    private Person _p;

    public PersonWithoutPhone(Person p)
    {
        _p = p;
    }

    [DataMember]
    internal string FullName
    {
        get { return _p.FullName; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    private int Age
    {
        get { return _p.Age; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string TelephoneNumber
    {
        get { return _p.TelephonNumber; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the answer would be "no"?

Comment: Yes the simple answer is no, sorry for not being more clear on that.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, you could use [DataMember( EmitDefaultValue=false)] and set fields you don't want to serialize to null or not initialize at all

E.g.

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    // This member is serialized.
    [DataMember]
    internal string FullName;

    [DataMember( EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string TelephoneNumber
    {
        get { return telephoneNumberValue; }
        set { telephoneNumberValue = value; }
    }
}
```

Then you may have 2 methods that load\create Person in 2 different ways

```
public Person LoadWithPhone() 
    {
        return new Person() { FullName = "Name", TelephoneNumber = "123456" };
    }

 public Person LoadWithoutPhone() 
    {
        return new Person() { FullName = "Name" }; //TelephoneNumber is null
    }
```

Then when serialize person created by second method, TelephoneNumber will not be serialized
This might be useful when load object from DB, you can have several methods that load different columns or have one that is constructing query on the fly and initialized object only with requested fields.